# Simple PHP MySQL message client

Tags: php, mysql, email, client, message

I am trying to create a simple PHP  MySQL driven message client.

So far I have two tables:

`users` which holds information about each person registered on the site. `userID`, `firstName`, `lastName` etc.

`mail` which contains a `MessageID`, `fromUserID`, `toUserID`, `messageSubject`, `messageBody` , `dateSent` etc.

Users can register and then log in. Once they are logged in they can view their 'inbox'.

What I am trying to figure out is how to list all the messages, and a preview for each message saying who it is from. Obviously I can get the `fromUserID` field from the `mail` table but that doesn't mean anything to the user, it is just a number, I want to use the `userID` and query the `users` table and pull from that the sender's first and last name.

I know I can use `JOIN` but I am not sure how to go about it, or can I use a sub query? What is better?

Any suggestions are very welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to want to join the users table, something like:

```
SELECT m.*, u.*
FROM mail m
  LEFT JOIN users u ON u.id = m.fromUserID
WHERE m.toUserID == 'LoggedInUserId'
```

Comment: I have tried this, only changing the `u.id` to `u.userID` and it threw an error `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '== '1001'' at line 1`. does it have to be `==`? Or could it be `LIKE`?

Comment: Excellent. Joins are nearly always going to be faster than subqueries.

Comment: Just a detail: `m.toUserID == 'LoggedInUserId'` should be `m.toUserID = 'LoggedInUserId'` (note there's only one `=`).

Answer (score 0):

Keep the userid in session when you validate the user.
then you can get the data using the below query.
select mail.* from mail m,users u where u.user_id=m.to_user_id and u.user_id=**logged in userid**

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your answer correctly, but I think it is not what I was after. I want to get the details of the sender, not of the person who is logged in.

Comment: I think you din't get me, we need to get not only sender infor but also messages from them. we pull the messages based on to_userid and he is nothing but the person logged in. I think I am clear this time.